# Failure to initialize EAC application in ATG Oracle commerce

Tags: oracle, atg, oracle-commerce

Endeca and database is installed property.
When there is an erro if i initialize the application using CIM.

```
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [deploy.pl] INFO:  Starting deployment template
   installation.
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [InstallConfigReader] INFO:  Parsing install config file
   /home/oracle/git/xxx_ecommerce/Endeca/endeca-deployment-template/xxx-ecommerce-install-config_en.xml.
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [AppDescriptorReader] INFO:  Parsing application descriptor
   file
   /home/oracle/git/xxx_ecommerce/Applications/B2CStore/src/main/deploy/CSAen/deploy.xml.
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [deploy.pl] INFO:  Deploying application into
   /usr/local/endeca/apps/CSAen
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [InstallConfigReader] INFO:  Parsing install config file
   /home/oracle/git/xxx_ecommerce/Endeca/endeca-deployment-template/xxx-ecommerce-install-config_en.xml.
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [AppDescriptorReader] INFO:  Parsing application descriptor
   file
   /home/oracle/git/xxx_ecommerce/Applications/B2CStore/src/main/deploy/CSAen/deploy.xml.
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [deploy.pl] INFO:  Processing install with id 'CSAApp'
04/26/2016 11:35:06 [deploy.pl] INFO:  Application successfully deployed.
----- Creating Endeca XM Sites...
----- Initializing Services...
Removing existing crawl configuration for crawl CSAen-last-mile-crawl (ignore errors if crawl doesn't exist)
exiting with error. com.endeca.itl.cas.cmd.CasCmdException: CSAen-last-mile-crawl was not found
Removing Record Store CSAen-data (ignore errors if Record Store doesn't exist)
Successfully deleted component: CSAen-data
Removing Record Store CSAen-dimvals (ignore errors if Record Store doesn't exist)
Successfully deleted component: CSAen-dimvals
Removing Dimension Value Id Manager CSAen-dimension-value-id-manager (ignore errors if Dimension Value Id Manager doesn't exist)
Removing existing application provisioning...
[04.26.16 11:35:14] INFO: Removing application. Any active components will be forced to stop.
[04.26.16 11:35:15] INFO: Removing definition for custom component 'IFCR'.
[04.26.16 11:35:15] INFO: Updating provisioning for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:15] INFO: Updating definition for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:15] SEVERE: Unable to remove site from IFCR

Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility$HttpStatusException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility execute - Service Unavailable (503):

[04.26.16 11:35:15] INFO: Removing definition for custom component 'CAS'.
[04.26.16 11:35:16] INFO: Updating provisioning for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:16] INFO: Updating definition for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:16] INFO: Removing definition for application 'CSAen'.
[04.26.16 11:35:16] INFO: Application 'CSAen' removed.
Creating Dimension Value Id Manager CSAen-dimension-value-id-manager
Creating Record Store CSAen-data
Successfully created component: CSAen-data
Successfully set recordstore configuration.
Creating Record Store CSAen-dimvals
Successfully created component: CSAen-dimvals
Setting EAC provisioning and performing initial setup...
[04.26.16 11:35:26] INFO: Checking definition from AppConfig.xml against existing EAC provisioning.
[04.26.16 11:35:26] INFO: Setting definition for application 'CSAen'.
[04.26.16 11:35:26] INFO: Setting definition for host 'AuthoringMDEXHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for host 'LiveMDEXHostA'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for host 'ReportGenerationHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for host 'WorkbenchHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for component 'AuthoringDgraph'.
> Building 93% > :refreshEndecadebug2: channel 0: window 999383 sent adjust 49193
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for component 'DgraphA1'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for script 'ReleaseUpdateLock'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for script 'PromoteAuthoringToLive'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for custom component 'IFCR'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Updating provisioning for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Updating definition for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:27] INFO: Setting definition for component 'LogServer'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for script 'DaySoFarReports'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for script 'DailyReports'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for script 'WeeklyReports'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for script 'DaySoFarHtmlReports'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for script 'DailyHtmlReports'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for script 'WeeklyHtmlReports'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for component 'WeeklyReportGenerator'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for component 'DailyReportGenerator'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for component 'DaySoFarReportGenerator'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for component 'WeeklyHtmlReportGenerator'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for component 'DailyHtmlReportGenerator'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for component 'DaySoFarHtmlReportGenerator'.
[04.26.16 11:35:28] INFO: Setting definition for custom component 'CAS'.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Updating provisioning for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Updating definition for host 'ITLHost'.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Setting definition for script 'BaselineUpdate'.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Setting definition for script 'PartialUpdate'.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Setting definition for component 'Dgidx'.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Definition updated.
[04.26.16 11:35:29] INFO: Provisioning site from prototype...
[04.26.16 11:35:30] SEVERE: Service Unavailable (503): [19:45:36] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 174 of 176 components ready)...
Occurred while executing line 3 of valid BeanShell script:
[[

1|
2|
3|    IFCR.provisionSite();
4|    CAS.importDimensionValueIdMappings("CSAen-dimension-value-id-manager",
5|          InitialSetup.getWorkingDir() + "/test_data/initial_dval_id_mappings.csv");
6|

]]

[04.26.16 11:35:30] SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'InitialSetup'. Releasing locks.

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke0 - null
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility$HttpStatusException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility execute - Service Unavailable (503): [19:45:36] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 174 of 176 components ready)...

Failure to initialize EAC application.
----- Starting Authoring DGraph...
[04.26.16 11:35:31] INFO: Checking definition from AppConfig.xml against existing EAC provisioning.
[04.26.16 11:35:31] INFO: Definition has not changed.
[04.26.16 11:35:31] INFO: [AuthoringMDEXHost] Starting component 'AuthoringDgraph'.
[04.26.16 11:35:35] INFO: Publishing Workbench 'authoring' configuration to MDEX 'AuthoringDgraph'
[04.26.16 11:35:35] INFO: Pushing authoring content to dgraph: AuthoringDgraph
[04.26.16 11:35:36] SEVERE: Service Unavailable (503): [19:45:42] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 174 of 176 components ready)...
Occurred while executing line 5 of valid BeanShell script:
[[

2|
3|        compId = invokingObject.getElementId();
4|        log.info("Publishing Workbench 'authoring' configuration to MDEX '" + compId + "'");
5|        IFCR.pushAuthoringContentToDgraphById(compId);
6|
7|
]]

[04.26.16 11:35:36] WARNING: Caught an exception while executing post-startup script for server component 'AuthoringDgraph'.

Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility$HttpStatusException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility execute - Service Unavailable (503): [19:45:42] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 174 of 176 components ready)...

----- Starting Live DGraph...
[04.26.16 11:35:37] INFO: Checking definition from AppConfig.xml against existing EAC provisioning.
[04.26.16 11:35:38] INFO: Definition has not changed.
[04.26.16 11:35:38] INFO: [LiveMDEXHostA] Starting component 'DgraphA1'.
[04.26.16 11:35:42] INFO: Publishing Workbench 'live' configuration to MDEX 'DgraphA1'
[04.26.16 11:35:42] INFO: Job #: update-dgraph-1461663342169 Sending update to server  - file: /tmp/soap-mdex4468043139973963937.xml
[04.26.16 11:35:42] INFO: The request to the Dgraph at localhost.localdomain:15000 was successfully sent. The return code was : 200
----- Promoting Content from Authoring to Live-----
[04.26.16 11:35:43] INFO: Checking definition from AppConfig.xml against existing EAC provisioning.
[04.26.16 11:35:43] INFO: Definition has not changed.
[04.26.16 11:35:43] INFO: Exporting MDEX tool contents to file CSAen.mdex.2016-04-26_11-35-43.zip
[04.26.16 11:35:44] SEVERE: Failed to create zip file or the key file associated with it
Occurred while executing line 8 of valid BeanShell script:
[[

 5|            // The zip is written to the local config directory for the live
 6|            // dgraph cluster.  A key file is stored along with the zip.
 7|            // This key file keeps the latest version of the zip file.
 8|            IFCR.exportConfigSnapshot(LiveDgraphCluster);
 9|
10|            // IFCR exportApplication
11|            // Used to export a particular node to disk. This on disk format will represent

]]

[04.26.16 11:35:44] SEVERE: Caught an exception while invoking method 'run' on object 'PromoteAuthoringToLive'. Releasing locks.

Caused by java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke0 - null
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppControlException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.script.Script runBeanShellScript - Error executing valid BeanShell script.
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.exception.AppConfigurationException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.component.IFCRComponent exportConfigSnapshot - Failed to create zip file or the key file associated with it
Caused by com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility$HttpStatusException
com.endeca.soleng.eac.toolkit.utility.IFCRUtility execute - Service Unavailable (503): [19:45:50] Workbench is starting up (112 of 112 bundles activated, 174 of 176 components ready)...

:refreshEndeca FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This typically happens when you have not installed Endeca correctly and has happened to me when I mistyped a port number during the installation of Endeca.  The various Endeca installers require information from the other components you have installed.

The giveaway for this error is the `503 Service Unavailable Error`

I suggest is that you reinstall Endeca and carefully follow the instructions in [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E67226_01/Common.112/pdf/GettingStarted.pdf).

Alternatively you can try to identify where the configuration error lies and amend the configuration within the Endeca installation folders but you might find that you have multiple issues which is why I recommend you simply reinstall.

Comment: I cant just reinstall edeca. because im not the one who installed it. and im not confident to do that, may be i will loose some config if i will do that. is there any thoubleshooting for this?

Comment: Can you log into experience manager and navigate to the admin page? There is an option to start and stop the various components for endeca. Confirm which components are running and / or you are able to manually start.